# Get record field values and check if a field is null on LWC connectedCallback

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want to get Account field values (Name and Site) on loading the component so I can later use them as aguments for apex methods. I also want to set a boolean variable to true if a field is not null so i can show or hide some text in the HTML. I used the same code on connectedCallback() and a buttonAction() that is called from a lightning-button tag

Here's the code I'm using

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire,track} from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
import SITE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Site';

export default class UpdateInfoAccount extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    accountObject = ACCOUNT_OBJECT;
    accountName='';
    @track testIfSiteNull=false;
    accountSite='';


    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [NAME_FIELD,SITE_FIELD] })
    record;

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('TEST 1: '+this.testIfSiteNull)
        this.accountName= this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, NAME_FIELD) : '';
        this.accountSite= this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, SITE_FIELD) : '';
        this.testIfSiteNull= this.accountSite!=='' && this.accountSite!==null ? true : false;
        console.log('init : Name '+this.accountName+'  Site '+this.accountSite);
        console.log('TEST 2: '+this.testIfSiteNull);

    }



    buttonAction(){
        console.log('TEST 3: '+this.testIfSiteNull);
        this.accountName= this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, NAME_FIELD) : '';
        this.accountSite= this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, SITE_FIELD) : '';
        this.testIfSiteNull= this.accountSite!=='' && this.accountSite!==null  ? true : false;
        console.log('Button: Name '+this.accountName+'  Site '+this.accountSite);
        console.log('TEST 4: '+this.testIfSiteNull);
    }

}
```

Here are the console log results:

> TEST 1: false
>
> init : Name   Site
>
> TEST 2: false
>
> TEST 3: false
>
> Button: Name Account 1  Site www.example.com
>
> TEST 4: true

Can you explain what happens here, and if there is any way I can solve this?

Comment: What is your exact question/issue?

Comment: Check with propertyorfunction(data,error)  from wire service weather a data is available to access which can be a before  connected callback hook fires or after.

Comment: @JayantDas I want the variable testIfSiteNull to be set to true (if field site is not null) when loading the page not after clicking a button

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments:

> I want the variable `testIfSiteNull` to be set to `true` (if field `Site` is not `null`) when loading the page not after clicking a button

You should be using [`renderedCallback()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_rendered) here instead of [`connectedCallback()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_dom).

From documentation for `connectedCallback()`:

> `connectedCallback()` lifecycle hook fires when a component is inserted into the DOM

whereas `renderedCallback()` mentions:

> Use it to perform logic after a component has finished the rendering phase.

Because you want to populate the field after your component has been rendered, using `renderedCallback()` will allow you to achieve so. So your JS function will look as:

```
renderedCallback() {
    console.log('TEST 1: '+this.testIfSiteNull)
    ...
    console.log('TEST 2: '+this.testIfSiteNull);
}
```

---

**Note:** Because your `record` property is a *wired* property, so you will be able to access `this.record.data` in any function only after lifecycle hooks. So if you try to use that in any lifecycle function, you will end up getting `undefined` exception. From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/data_wire_service_about):

> The property is assigned a default value after component construction and before any other lifecycle event. The default value is an object with `data` and `error` properties of `undefined`.

Comment: You mean `record` property in singular, right?  The OP has it in singular, not plural.  I'm new to LWC so I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: @DavidCheng Ah! Thanks for pointing that out, it is `record` indeed, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a simpler approach and just handle it in your `@wire` by changing the `@wire` to a function instead:

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [NAME_FIELD,SITE_FIELD] })
  record( { error, data }) {

    if( data ){
      this.accountName = ( data.fields.hasOwnProperty.call( data.fields, NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName ) && data.fields[ NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName ].value ) || "";
      this.accountSite = ( data.fields.hasOwnProperty.call( data.fields, SITE_FIELD.fieldApiName ) && data.fields[ SITE_FIELD.fieldApiName ].value ) || "";
      ... set your other values here
    }
    else if( error ){
      console.error( "error: ", error );
    }
  }
```