# LWC renderedCallback not retrieving a wired record

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a Lightning web component that is being called from a quick action custom button from a custom object record page.  When the component is loaded, I need to retrieve the record so I can get a field value from it.

[This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251448/get-record-field-values-and-check-if-a-field-is-null-on-lwc-connectedcallback) says to use a wire with renderedCallback.  I've tried it but the wire is not retrieving the record in the callback.

In my console logs, I see the correct recordId value in the callback, but the wired `platoonEvent`is empty and the `data` is undefined:

```
in callback
recordId: "a1l0m000000IHxOAAW"
Platoon event: {}
Platoon event data: undefined
```

I've tried connectedCallback but that doesn't work either.

Is there an issue with the fact that this LWC is wrapped in an aura component because I'm using a quick action custom button?

**Javascript**:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { createRecord, getRecord, getFieldValue, updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import OCCASION_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Occasion__c';
import OCCASION_PLATOONID from '@salesforce/schema/Occasion__c.Service_Platoon__c';

export default class BatchRegistration extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    platoonId;

    // Get the platoon event record so we can get the platoon ID field.
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [OCCASION_PLATOONID] })
    platoonEvent;

    /* Functions start here */

    // Initialize
    renderedCallback() {
        console.log('in callback');
        console.log('recordId: ' + JSON.stringify(this.recordId));
        console.log('Platoon event: ' + JSON.stringify(this.platoonEvent));
        console.log('Platoon event data: ' + JSON.stringify(this.platoonEvent.data));
        this.platoonId = getFieldValue(this.platoonEvent.data, OCCASION_PLATOONID);
    }
```

Note: I've also tried this but it doesn't work either:

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ['Occasion__c.Service_Platoon__c'] })
platoonEvent;
```

Comment: I am assuming your markup is blank.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I don't use platoonEvent or platoonId in the markup, I want to use them for Apex parameters once a user clicks a button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_rendered):

> When a component rerenders, all the expressions used in the template
>   are reevaluated. Due to mutations, a component is usually rendered many times during its lifespan in an application.

Now, as you are not using `platoonEvent` in the markup, the expression won't be evaluated, and the wire won't be called.

Fix: Use `platoonEvent` in the markup like

```
  <template>

    In my template

     Record Id is : {recordId}
    <br/>
    <template if:true={platoonEvent.data}>
        {platoonEvent.data.fields.Service_Platoon__c.value}
    </template>
</template>
```

Also the thing to remember is `renderedCallback` will be called multiple times, the first time its called, it won't have the value. You can see it from your debug logs