# LWC not retrieving wired record data

Tags: lightning-web-components, quickaction, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a simple LWC component that isn't able to perform getRecord.  As in the situation in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275423/lwc-renderedcallback-not-retrieving-a-wired-record), I need it to be invoked in a quick action, so it's wrapped in an aura component (if that matters).  Here is the js:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from "lwc";
import { getRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";

const oppFields = ["Opportunity.Name"];

export default class testOPP extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;

  // Fetch fields of current opportunity.
  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", oppFields })
  opp;
  renderedCallback() {
    console.log("in callback");
    console.log("recordId: " + JSON.stringify(this.recordId));
    console.log("Opp: " + JSON.stringify(this.opp));
    console.log("Opp data: " + JSON.stringify(this.opp.data));
  }
}
```

And here is the markup:

```
<template>
    In my template
    Record Id is : {recordId}
    <br />
    <template if:true={opp.data}>
        {opp.data.fields.Name.value}
    </template>
</template>
```

The console shows that recordId is getting populated, but the renderedCallback is only called once.  I thought it was supposed to be called several times until the data is pulled down.  Here is the console log:

```
in callback
recordId: "006M000000MGcpvIAD"
Opp: {}
Opp data: undefined
```

Thanks in advance for any thoughts!

- Randy

Answer (score 2):

A small grammar error:

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", oppFields })
```

Defines a property `oppFields` on the parameters, but it needs to be `fields`:

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: oppFields })
```

Comment: That did the trick!  Big thanks, @sfdxfox.  (Don't have reputation points so can't upvote.)

Comment: @RandyTrigg You can click the ✅ to mark it as an answer, which will give you some reputation. Also, I forgot to give you a +1, so there you go.