# Fire @wire after renderedCallback

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm trying to retrieve data from Apex using `@wire`. However, I do not want to fire this event before `renderedCallback()`. This is because I'm receiving a parameter required to fire a wired event which is initially set as undefined. This parameter is not used in HTML.

```
@api myRecords = [];

@track _myParam;
@api
get myParam() {
    return this._myParam;
}
set myParam(val) {
    this._myParam = val;
}

renderedCallback(){
    console.log("---myParam: " + this.myParam);
}

@wire(getInformation, {param1: this.myParam})
wiredAttachments({ error, data }){
    if (data){
        this.myRecords = data;
    } else if (error){
        //do something
    }
}
```

I looked at a [similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275423/lwc-renderedcallback-not-retrieving-a-wired-record) but unable to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A strong side of functions decorated with `@wire` is that it is possible to use reactive variables, which are prefixed with `$` in the adapter config object. Whenever the reactive variable changes - the wire method will be executed. In order to use a reactive variable as a param, omit `this` and use the `$` symbol as a string.

```
@api myRecords = [];

_myParam;

@api
get myParam() {
    return this._myParam;
}
set myParam(val) {
    this._myParam = val;
}

@wire(getInformation, {param1: '$_myParam'})
wiredAttachments({ error, data }){
    if (data){
        this.myRecords = data;
    } else if (error){
        //do something
    }
}
```

---

refer [Understand the Wire Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/data_wire_service_about) documentation to learn more about it